# AWS profile not being saved

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I login to AWS and have a credential file, which is populated.

I run `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile=default`

and get the details:

```json
{
    "UserId": "xxxxxxx",
    "Account": "xxxxxx",
    "Arn": "xxxxx"
}
```

I try and set the default profile and run without the profile flag

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

I get an error:

> An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the
> GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the
> request is invalid.

I am on Windows 10.

Any ideas why?

Comment: At a guess you have incorrect [AWS_xxx environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) set in your environment and they're being used in preference to your default credentials profile.

Comment: Or specifically AWS_PROFILE set to something other than "default"

Comment: Do you have any AWS-related Environment variables set? It sounds like there is something setting a 'security token' outside of the credentials file.